# Semantic segmentation task issue

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to do a semantic segmentation task on the `cityscapes` dataset, with model as `DeepLabv3` and `mobilenetv2`. While giving input to model as a `dataloader`:

```
for batch, (x, y) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
                x, y = x.to(device), y.to(device)
                pred_mask = model(x)
```

I am getting a runtime error:

`RuntimeError: Wrong input shape height=480, width=3. Expected image height and width divisible by 8. Consider pad your images to shape (480, 8)`.

When I printed shapes of both x and y, I got:

```
torch.Size([32, 480, 480, 3])
torch.Size([32, 480, 480])
```

My model is taking 3 as width, and not as channels. What to do for this?

This is code for model:

```
mobilenet_v2 = smp.encoders.get_encoder("mobilenet_v2", in_channels = 3, weights = 'imagenet')

class Segmodel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Segmodel, self).__init__()
        num_classes = 30
        self.model = smp.DeepLabV3(encoder_name = "mobilenet_v2", encoder_weights = "imagenet", in_channels=3, classes = num_classes, activation = None)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)
```

Runtime error resulted

Comment: PyTorch models expect input in the form of `[N C H W]` by default. You need to convert your input shape from `[32, 480, 480, 3]` to `[32, 3, 480, 480]`.